# Cloudera Hadoop quick Start VM Impala Error

Tags: virtual-machine, cloudera, impala

I am trying to run impala on cloudera quick start vm. I installed impala / impala-server / impala-state-store / impala-catalog. 
Then I did impala-shell and got following message :

`Starting Impala Shell without Kerberos authentication
Error connecting: TTransportException, Could not connect to localhost.localdomain:21000
Welcome to the Impala shell. Press TAB twice to see a list of available commands.

Copyright (c) 2012 Cloudera, Inc. All rights reserved.

(Shell build version: Impala Shell v1.4.0-cdh4-INTERNAL (08fa346) built on Mon Jul 14 15:52:52 PDT 2014)
[Not connected] >`

Then I did `connect;`
it shows output as -

`[Not connected] > connect;
Error connecting: TTransportException, Could not connect to localhost.localdomain:21000
[Not connected] >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

impalad isn't running on that machine so it can't connect, so you need to start the impala service. On the cloudera quick start VM, it is easiest via the Cloudera Manager (one of the two web pages you saw upon startup).

If you wish to confirm that impalad isn't running, try this:

ps -ef | grep impala

you should see something like this if it is running:

impala   21735 35332 83 10:45 ?        01:48:53 /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.2.0-1.cdh5.2.0.p0.36/lib/impala/sbin-retail/impalad --flagfile=/var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/71325-impala-IMPALAD/impala-conf/impalad_flags